# Creating a postgres user

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3

I want to make a typical user in postgres that will be used by my web application.

1. The web application will require access to all tables.
2. The user should be able to read/write to all tables (select, update, delete, insert)

All tables belong to the public schema

What is the best practise for creating this user?

database name:  acmeinc
user: acmeuser

I tried this so far and I was not able to even update a table (permission error on the relation):

```
create user acmeuser
grant all privileges on database acmeinc to acmeuser
alter schema public owner to acmeuser

ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA public GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON TABLES TO acmeuser
```

**Update**:

I was running the above like:

```
psql acmeinc -c "create user acmeuser"
```

Should I be creating a role and then associating the user acmeuser to the role?

Comment: You forgot the semicolons.

Comment: I updated my question to show how I ran the statements, I'll try again with the semicolons.  BTW, when I ran the commands, I did get a response back like "GRANT".  Still getting the error ```ERROR:  permission denied for relation tableabc```

Comment: At which command did you get the permission denied message?

Comment: ```update table123 set col3='23' where id=1;```   Selects work fine.

Comment: Ah. Granting on a database doesn't grant on tables within it. Also alter default privs only affects tables created after that is run. You want grant ... on all tables in schema.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your issue stems from two misunderstandings around `GRANT`:

- Granting on a database doesn't grant on tables within it, it only grants rights on the database object its self; and
- `ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES` only affects tables created *after* that is run, it doesn't change existing tables.

You want `GRANT ... ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA ...`.

Comment: I have to run a separate query for sequences and functions?